# How to upgrade PostgreSQL from version 9.1 to version 9.5 without losing data?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I'm using the PostgreSQL database for my OPEN ERP application (on Ubuntu 12.04
LTS).
Are there any detailed instructions on how to upgrade PostgreSQL database?

Comment: what makes you think you are going to lose data?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html  and https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_pg_upgrade_on_Ubuntu/Debian but I think Ubuntu's package manager takes care of that if you run `apt-get upgrade`

Comment: i'm not clear with the steps mentioned in the documentation link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html Could you please elaborate in simple terminology

Comment: Hey! I got succeeded in upgrading from postgres 9.1 to 9.5 on  windows platform. Is it the same or do I need to specifically follow any steps in ubuntu. Why I'm feared of data loss is it's my production server. If this is answerable do the needful. Thankyou